Working with editors and pending custom post types
I have found a problem that I don't think WordPress is capable of handling
I developed a CPT 'service-providers' and gave users capabilities to edit their own listing. Once they add a new listing or modify their existing listing, it goes into a pending status until it is reviewed and approved.
Problem 1: A listing that has been on the site since forever was modified by the owner - wordpress unpublished the post until it was approved - I was unwittingly of the opinion that the existing post would just stay as is until the content was approved and then would show the new data... We're effectively encouraging listing managers to login and remove their listing from the site...

Is there no way to modify a post and have it reviewed WITHOUT unpublishing it?

Problem 2: There were 2 CPTs awaiting review - when I realised that they had been unpublished, I just approved them to get them back on the site.  Then I realised I had put some 300 redirects in place for pages Google flagged with 404 (because they were unpublished) - so I needed to find these listings and make sure their URL wasn't being redirected. There was no way to find the most recently updated CPTs.

Is there no way to show the most recently edited CPTs?


we can better help you if you ask only one question at the time. edit your question to keep only the first problem. and you can post other questions separately.

in wordpress you can customise everything in writing your own plugin. I recommend that you write all functionalities that you need and then you will see all the steps you need to do in your plugin.
